# Handle data via URL to vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an email with some encrypted data for password changes. I want to open a URL with this data as query parameters like this:

```
<button onclick="window.location.href='http://127.0.0.1:8080/changePW?c1=${username.iv}&c2= $ {username.content}'">
```

How would I specify the route in Vue Router? Here is what I have tried:

```
{
  path: '/changePW?c1=val1&c2=val2',
  name: 'changePW',
  component: changePassw
}
```

Would I use just the name in my public pages or the path with query parameters?

```
const publicPages = ['/', '/privacy', '/privacyGen', '/changePW']
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are the route `params`.

```
{
  path: '/changePW?c1=val1&c2=val2',
  name: 'changePW',
  component: changePassw
  props: (route) => {
    c1: route.query.c1,
    c2: route.query.c2,
  }
}
```

Then in your `changePassw` component you would take those two in as `props` like this:

```
props: {
  c1: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  },
  c2: {
    type: String,
    default: '',
  }
}
```

As a complete side note I would consider updating your naming convention as `c1` and `c2` are likely to mean nothing to the next developer, and for your component names you've already spelled out `changePassw` so why not add the extra 3 letters to make it more complete like `changePassword`? :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Tho it's giving me a syntax error on the props. 

Also I can't open the link from my email button. Is the syntax there correct?

Also when I open the url directly in the browser `http://localhost:8080/?c1=test&c2=test1` I get redirected on my homepage.

Comment: @whyme you are opening the home page with query string parameters in that URL, not the `/changePW` route. What are the syntax errors it's giving you with what I wrote?

Comment: I tried it without the props now. Just using the query parameters and a normal path `'/changePW'` and in the component `this.$route.query;` and this also seems to work. But the props didn't sadly.

Comment: I updated the answer a bit - I think I had the syntax wrong as I was just typing this out. Try setting the props to `route.query.c1`, then they should work as props (as long as your component is setup to take them in)

Comment: But I dont neet the `path: '/changePW?c1=val1&c2=val2'`? I mean, if I just use it as `path: '/changePW'` it seems to work too.